# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 error on ALL Magento MySQL setup files after migration

Tags: mysql, magento, migration

I get the following error on all Magento MySQL setup files, after I have moved the website to a new hosting company. The new hosting company is running on Plesk / Apache. The website used to work perfectly.

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use nea

Comment: Can you post the complete output from MySQL? It seems to be truncated.

Answer (score 1):

try this
Simply change line 41 in \app\etc\config.xml

```
<initStatements>SET NAMES utf8</initStatements>
```

to

```
<initStatements>SET NAMES utf8; SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS = 1</initStatements>
```